# Get Max Value From A Row in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, max

I'm having a problem with SSRS 2008 R2. I have a matrix which contains a count of failed codes with the failed codes being the rows and days being the columns.

What I'd like to do is determine the maximum value in each of the rows, then use this to calculate a percentage and apply a conditional format. The expression I've tried to use for this is:

```
=iif((Max(Count(Fields!failed_code.Value),"failed_code") * 0.9) < Count(Fields!failed_code.Value),"red","white")
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

The backgroundcolor expression for the text box 'failed_code1_InAutoSubTotal1' contains a nested aggregate that does not specify a scope.

How do I set the scope so I can determine the max row value?

Comment: Would you be able to add some sample data and your desired output? It's not clear (to me, at least) exactly what the you're comparing and how this should be applied.

Comment: The error you mentioned is referring to the Count aggregate you used. It doesn't have a group specified like you did for the Max aggregate. Check if "failed_code" is really the name of your GROUP or is that just the name of a field in your dataset?